# Zurb Foundation and IE 8

Tags: internet-explorer-8, zurb-foundation

The css example below works in in all supported browsers with the exception of IE8 (not focusing on anything lower than IE 8). I'm using the latest version of Foundation.

The columns stack in IE8 when they should float. Actually see the float:left; attribute applied in the styles but they do not float.

What does work is if I add the css class names row, column six and so on directly to my mark up however I would prefer not to do so.

I can't seem to pinpoint the issue in IE 8...any suggestion would be much appreciated.

**Works:**

```
<div class="content-wrap row">
  <div class="primary six columns"></div>
  <div class="secondary six columns"></div>
</div>
```

**Does not work:**

```
.content-wrap {
  @include outerRow();
  .primary {
    @include column(6);
  }
  .secondary {
    @include column(6);
  }
}
```

Comment: Does the layout work at desktop resolution?

Answer (score 4):

The latest version of Foundation at the time of writing is Foundation 4. It's grid does not support IE8, but you can add support for it. See the following links.

[FoundationGoogle Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/foundation-framework-/ZFn7GBuEQTQ)

[gist](https://gist.github.com/hatefulcrawdad/5068210):

```
/* The Grid ---------------------- */
.lt-ie9 .row { width: 940px; max-width: 100%; min-width: 768px; margin: 0 auto; }
.lt-ie9 .row .row { width: auto; max-width: none; min-width: 0; margin: 0 -15px; }
.lt-ie9 .row.large-collapse .column, 
.lt-ie9 .row.large-collapse .columns { padding: 0; }
.lt-ie9 .row .row { width: auto; max-width: none; min-width: 0; margin: 0 -15px; }
.lt-ie9 .row .row.large-collapse { margin: 0; }

.lt-ie9 .column, .lt-ie9 .columns { float: left; min-height: 1px; padding: 0 15px; position: relative; }
.lt-ie9 .column.large-centered, .columns.large-centered { float: none; margin: 0 auto; }

.lt-ie9 [class*="column"] + [class*="column"]:last-child { float: right; }
.lt-ie9 [class*="column"] + [class*="column"].end { float: left; }

.lt-ie9 .large-1, 
.lt-ie9 .row .large-1 { width: 8.33333%; }

.lt-ie9 .large-2, 
.lt-ie9 .row .large-2 { width: 16.66667%; }

.lt-ie9 .large-3, 
.lt-ie9 .row .large-3 { width: 25%; }

.lt-ie9 .large-4, 
.lt-ie9 .row .large-4 { width: 33.33333%; }

.lt-ie9 .large-5, 
.lt-ie9 .row .large-5 { width: 41.66667%; }

.lt-ie9 .large-6, 
.lt-ie9 .row .large-6 { width: 50%; }

.lt-ie9 .large-7, 
.lt-ie9 .row .large-7 { width: 58.33333%; }

.lt-ie9 .large-8, 
.lt-ie9 .row .large-8 { width: 66.66667%; }

.lt-ie9 .large-9, 
.lt-ie9 .row .large-9 { width: 75%; }

.lt-ie9 .large-10, 
.lt-ie9 .row .large-10 { width: 83.33333%; }

.lt-ie9 .large-11, 
.lt-ie9 .row .large-11 { width: 91.66667%; }

.lt-ie9 .large-12,
.lt-ie9 .row .large-12 { width: 100%; }

.lt-ie9 .row .large-offset-1 { margin-left: 8.33333%; }
.lt-ie9 .row .large-offset-2 { margin-left: 16.66667%; }
.lt-ie9 .row .large-offset-3 { margin-left: 25%; }
.lt-ie9 .row .large-offset-4 { margin-left: 33.33333%; }
.lt-ie9 .row .large-offset-5 { margin-left: 41.66667%; }
.lt-ie9 .row .large-offset-6 { margin-left: 50%; }
.lt-ie9 .row .large-offset-7 { margin-left: 58.33333%; }
.lt-ie9 .row .large-offset-8 { margin-left: 66.66667%; }
.lt-ie9 .row .large-offset-9 { margin-left: 75%; }
.lt-ie9 .row .large-offset-10 { margin-left: 83.33333%; }

.lt-ie9 .pull-2 { right: 16.66667%; }
.lt-ie9 .pull-3 { right: 25%; }
.lt-ie9 .pull-4 { right: 33.33333%; }
.lt-ie9 .pull-5 { right: 41.66667%; }
.lt-ie9 .pull-6 { right: 50%; }
.lt-ie9 .pull-7 { right: 58.33333%; }
.lt-ie9 .pull-8 { right: 66.66667%; }
.lt-ie9 .pull-9 { right: 75%; }
.lt-ie9 .pull-10 { right: 83.33333%; }

.lt-ie9 .push-2 { left: 16.66667%; }
.lt-ie9 .push-3 { left: 25%; }
.lt-ie9 .push-4 { left: 33.33333%; }
.lt-ie9 .push-5 { left: 41.66667%; }
.lt-ie9 .push-6 { left: 50%; }
.lt-ie9 .push-7 { left: 58.33333%; }
.lt-ie9 .push-8 { left: 66.66667%; }
.lt-ie9 .push-9 { left: 75%; }
.lt-ie9 .push-10 { left: 83.33333%; }

/* Nicolas Gallagher's micro clearfix */
.lt-ie9 .row { *zoom: 1; }
.lt-ie9 .row:before, .row:after { content: " "; display: table; }
.lt-ie9 .row:after { clear: both; }
```