# IE8: invisible third-level navigation menu in Foundation 5.2

Tags: jquery, html, css, internet-explorer-8, zurb-foundation

I'm on a suicide mission to support IE8 with a Foundation 5.2-based site. Things have gone fairly well, but I'm stuck on a problem I can't seem to figure out: there's a multi-level flyout menu (operating on click, not hover), and the third level of said menu appears to be in the right place, just never shows up—in IE8.

Here's what that looks like (client identity obscured):

[image]

It's an absolutely-positioned element, so I've Googled around and tried many unsuccessful tricks:

- setting progressively-higher z-indexes starting with the outer most container and working my way to the menu
- forcing `overflow: visible`, `opacity: 1`, `display: block`, `clip: auto` on the missing `ul` and its parents
- manually setting generous widths and heights thinking maybe the `ul` isn't getting hasLayout

The only thing that gets close is setting `position: relative` on the `ul`. This results in a silly and unusuable page layout, of course, but I can at least *see* the menu items for a change.

I've set up a Fiddle using assets straight out of the development pile: http://jsfiddle.net/24TKa/

I know that Foundation 5.2 does not offer support for IE8, and while I'd love a magical fix it'd be great to understand exactly why this third-level menu refuses to show itself.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Zurb Foundation and IE 8](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13639499/zurb-foundation-and-ie-8)

Comment: foundation 5 doesnt support IE8

Comment: @nol Yes, I mentioned being aware of that in the question. I'm not looking for support where it doesn't exist, just to understand why a very specific thing is failing.

Answer (score 0):

> why this third-level menu refuses to show itself.

It has `overflow:hidden`, and the `width` of the default relative container is not being applied to IE8 via the Foundation stylesheet, but works when `position:relative` is set on the nested `ul` via an inline style.